# Boss is an alcoholic, yells all the time

Tags: professionalism

I work for a startup, my CEO is a drunk, loud and abusive. He yells at people, and makes it unnecessarily stressful to work. I know, there are deadlines, and we all are affected by them, and strive to meet them, but is yelling warranted? I think I'll quit very soon, please advise. Am I right in feeling like I want to run away and quit the job? I'm hanging on by the skin of my teeth.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: This site isn't about open discussions, it's about questions and answers. That's why your contribution is on hold, because it's not a question.

Comment: "`I think I'll quit very soon, please advise`" - my advice is to make "soon" sooner

Comment: "I think I'll quit very soon, please advise." No, don't even go back there. You said it yourself. He is "a drunk, loud and abusive". You do not want to quit in person with someone abusive like that. Send him an email. That's it. End of story. You can email your former co-workers as well, but do not try to save everyone. Save yourself at least. It's their decision if they want to stay.

Answer (score 6):

Nobody should be drunk in their workplace, especially CEO.

**Yes, you need to quit.** I am pretty sure you already know that, and confirmation from strangers on Internet isn't necessary, but here it is anyway.